# Python Creating and Importing Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote functions that are applyRules(ch), processString(Oldstr) and named it lsystems.py
And I put

```
import lsystems
def main():
    inst = applyRules("F")
    print(inst)
main()
```

and saved it as mainfunctioni

However, when I try to run mainfunctioni, it says 'applyRules' is not defined.
Doesn't it work because I put import lsystems?

What should I do to work my mainfunctioni through lsystems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it with `module.function()` format. So in this case, it should be called like as follows:

```
 inst = lsystems.applyRules("F")
```

You have to access all the methods from your module with the same format. For processString(Oldstr), it should be similar.

```
test_string = lsystems.processString("Somestring")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module using `import <module>` syntax, you need to access the module's contents through its namespace, like so:

```
import lsystems

def main():
    inst = lsystems.applyRules("F")
    print(inst)

main()
```

Alternatively, you can directly import the function from the module:

```
from lsystems import applyRules

def main():
    inst = applyRules("F")
    print(inst)

main()
```